# Is there a way to do this in javascript? or will it work import/export

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, import, export

```
//file1.js
    export function foo() {
        //todo
    }

//file2.js
    export function bar() {
        file1.foo();
        //todo
    }

//main.js
    import * as file1 from './file1'
    if(true) {
        import('./file2.js').then((_) => {
            //bar calls file1.foo()
            bar();
        });
```

- As you see there is file1.js that exports a function. A file2.js that
  also exports a function, but it uses a function present in file1.js

  There is another file main.js which imports file1.js always at start.
  And if certain condition is met, imports file2.js and call function
  bar() which calls foo() present in file1.js

  Will this work if files are imported in this way? If not are there
  any other options to make it work?

Comment: file2 has to import file1 itself or file2 won't be able to use file1.  Imports are not global - they are local to a module (they may share a cache, but a given module still needs to import the things it uses).

Comment: Why wouldn't it work? Can you explain the issue you are having or restate the question?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to import the file where the function is called.

```js
//file1.js
export function foo() {  
  //todo
}

//file2.js
import * as file1 from "./file1.js"

export function bar() {
  file1.foo();
  //todo
}

//main.js
import * as file2 from "./file2.js";

file2.bar();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So this is the only way I guess. I will have to import the file everywhere I need it. Importing file1.js once to the main.js won't work.